# python cannot import module

Tags: python, docker

I have a problem. I want to use the docker-py(0.4.0) library, but i cannot import it.
My code looks as followed:

docker.py

```
import docker

c = docker.Client()

c.info()
```

then i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./docker.py", line 1, in <module>
    import docker
File "/home/vagrant/docker.py", line 3, in <module>
  c = docker.Client()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

when i run it from the python interpreter it works

```
>>> import docker
>>> c = docker.Client()
>>> c.info()
{u'KernelVersion': u'3.13.0-35-generic', u'NFd': 12, u'MemoryLimit': 1, 
u'InitSha1': u'',u'SwapLimit': 0, u'Driver': u'devicemapper', 
u'IndexServerAddress': u'https://index.docker.io/v1/', u'NGoroutines': 11, 
u'Images': 310, u'InitPath': u'/usr/bin/docker', u'Containers': 1, 
u'ExecutionDriver': u'native-0.2', u'Debug': 0, u'NEventsListener': 0, 
u'DriverStatus': [[u'Pool Name', u'docker-8:1-140095-pool'], 
[u'Pool Blocksize', u'64 Kb'], [u'Data file', /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data'], [u'Metadata file', u'/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata'], 
[u'Data Space Used', u'3602.1 Mb'], [u'Data Space Total', u'102400.0 Mb'], 
[u'Metadata Space Used', u'8.7 Mb'], [u'Metadata Space Total', u'2048.0 Mb']], 
u'OperatingSystem': u'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS', u'IPv4Forwarding': 1}
>>>
```

I don't use any virtualenv, only the system python. I have try it on two machines, but same result

Can someone explaine me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

your filename is `docker.py` and when you say `import docker` it tries to import itself. Try renaming your file and run it again